# encodeBase64 and decodeBase64 not visible

Tags: java, encryption, aes

So, I used Github copilot to generate an AES encryption/decryption snippet.
This is the code:

```
package crypto;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.util.Base64;
public class aes{
   //aes encryption    
   public static String encrypt(String plainText, String key) {
       try {
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
           SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
           byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
           return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }
  public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, String key) {
       try {
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
           SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
           byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText));
           return new String(decrypted);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

It looked good, so I pressed TAB.
After I tried compiling the main class, this happened:

```
dfmaaa1@dfmaaa1-dell:~/[project]/crypto$ javac aes.java
aes.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
            return new String(new Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));
                                        ^
  symbol:   class encodeBase64
  location: class Base64
aes.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(new Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText));
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class decodeBase64
  location: class Base64
2 errors
```

How can I make these exceptions go away?

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: Base64 is only available since java 8

Comment: Which Base64 class is being imported? There are *loads* of them. But `new Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted)` is almost certainly wrong... I suspect you mean `Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted)` - no `new` there.

Comment: @MiltonCardoso openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @JonSkeet That's what github copilot pasted, but that also didn't work, same error

Answer (score 1):

For `java.util.Base64`, use `Base64.getEncoder().encode(...)` and `Base64.getDecoder().decode(...)`.

```
import java.util.Base64;
// ...
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new byte[]{ /* ... */ });
new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode("str"));
```